# Excel VBA: Displaying table data using drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in VBA. I have a worksheet in Excel where tables for each individual month is created to calculate the total amount of manhours for each month. The tables are located in different columns in the worksheet. The data in this table is populated using manually inputted data in respective sheets created for each month.

Currently, this is being done manually and the list is getting very long. I would like to improve on this by creating a dropdown list filter and retrieving the respective data from each month and year and displaying it in the form of a calendar instead. Can anyone guide me on how this can be done?

This is an example of the worksheet I want to compile:

[image: sample table]

I want it to look something like this where the data for the data will change according to the data I retrieve from the respective months. The months and years will be in the form of drop down list.

[image: sample table]

The workbook will be updated on a daily basis. The names of the worksheets involved will be named in a format like this: Jul'19, Aug'19, Sept'20, etc. There will be more worksheets created over time.

Comment: "creating a dropdown list filter and retrieving the respective data from each month and year and displaying it in the form of a calendar instead" does not say too much. Do you exactly know how that form looking as a calendar should look? If yes, it would be good to also show us what do you have in mind... I cannot understand what is to be done.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru I have made the changes. Thank you

Comment: OK. But which would be the purpose of this approach? Would you like to make inputs on the form, or only to see it in the way you show us? In order to see it, it would be enough to create a listBox and populate it with the appropriate month situation. if you want/need to input data in the form instead of the sheet, the thing becomes much more complicated. And the question will be again, why do you feel that it will be better than inputting data directly in the sheet?

Comment: @FaneDuru I would only need it to be presented like the way I show it here. This is because the data presented here is a computed sum of several other components in the other respective worksheets. Also, how can I specify it in the program such that if August and 2020 is chosen, it will look for the worksheet 'Aug'20', if July and 2020 is chosen, then it will look for 'Jul'20' and vice versa?

Comment: Let us firstly clarify what is to be down. Then how to be done... So, would you only like to load them as they are for specific months, but **without having the possibility to modify anything**? If yes, i will explain you how I see the solution for such a task. If I will find some time, I maybe will create a piece of code, explaining what controls should  exist on the form. But, which exactly are the sheets name? i can see in your pictures 'May-19', 'Jul-19' etc. and in the form you show us the word 'September' and another combo keeping '2020'.

Comment: If you only need some ideas, it can be OK. if you want seeing a working piece of code, you must explain this aspect in details... Should the application load the sheets name, should the code use a logical rule to convert them in what you need, should it exist an equivalence list making the match between 'Jul-19' with 'July' in first combo and `2019' in the second one?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @FaneDuru. Yes, I will be loading them as it is as all modifications will be done on the other worksheets. As for the combo, I'm not very sure on what's the best way in naming them as if I named it according to the worksheets, there will be a need for it to be constantly updated manually (?) if we have more worksheets created. Or is there a way for us to read in the worksheet names and use it as options for the combo?

Comment: @FaneDuru If you do not have time, it would be great if you can give me a rough idea on how this can be done and I will go give it a try for the time being :)

Comment: Now I am driving...

Comment: If you intend to use the worksheets name, the combo will be automatically updated when the form is loaded, or if you want doing that, using a button.

Comment: I will prepare an answer, writing the form code and linking a picture, in order to see how it looks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, create a form and place the next code in its module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        Me.cbMonth.AddItem sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub

Private Sub cbMonth_Change()
  Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, Tbl As ListObject
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set sh = wb.Sheets(Me.cbMonth.Value)
  Set Tbl = sh.ListObjects(1)
  arr = Tbl.Range.Value
   With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = UBound(arr, 2)
        .ColumnWidths = "40;25;22;23;22;22;22;48;40"
        .list = arr
   End With
End Sub
```

So, you must place a combo box named `cbMonth` and a list box named 'ListBox1`.

On the form `Initialize` event the combo box is populated with the sheets name.

On the combo box `Change` event the 'ListBox1` is populated with the first table range of the selected sheet name. So, in each sheet should exist only one table, or, if more tables, the necessary one must be the first.

You will also be able to input data in the list box, using its `DblClick` event. The user will be asked about the day where the data to be inputted and then, the sheet can be updated, too...

[image: The form picture]

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I just tried this and it works like a charm! thanks a lot!!

Comment: @jqy: Glad I could help! But don't you like to have the possibility to also fill the hours using the form list box? Of course, updating the table, too...

Comment: ah yes! Will be looking into these implementations in the future too!

Comment: @jqy: If you will place a new question on the issue, posting the existing code and tag me (here), I can help. I have something in my head regarding the way to be done...