# Inputting values using ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

This is a continuation from [@FaneDuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233308/faneduru)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021600/excel-vba-displaying-table-data-using-drop-down-list/65028909?noredirect=1#comment114981443_65028909). With my current code, it will pull data from each worksheet and display it on the form.

I would like to allow for the input of different values on the form instead of only displaying them.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        Me.cbMonth.AddItem sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub

Private Sub cbMonth_Change()
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, Tbl As ListObject
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.Sheets(Me.cbMonth.Value)
    Set Tbl = sh.ListObjects(1)
    arr = Tbl.Range.Value
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = UBound(arr, 2)
        .ColumnWidths = "40;25;22;23;22;22;22;48;40"
        .list = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a textbox to add values to listbox.
Something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
     Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```